# My computer gets stuck at the following screen while trying to install ubuntu 16.04.3 from usb stick

Tags: 16.04, boot, system-installation, usb

Computer gets stuck in the following screen while trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 from an USB stick. Please refer screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: No I checked that question , my problem seems to be different

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens when trying to use a lower version of a USB port than recommended. An older version of the BIOS is also a contributor to the issue. Work around install by using a CD/dvd drive or using the wubi.exe...however there might be issues with viruses when using wubi. CD/dvd drive installation works smooth as silk